# Geocode with csv file does not work

Tags: geocoding

I'm trying to map data that I uploaded with an csv file. Originally this data set only included the country code, e.g. BD, for Bangladesh. I tried to geocode it by admin region  and selected the column where the country code is stored. It gives me an error message.

Then I updated the data file with more specific information on the location: address, city and country. But this also did not work.

What do I do wrong? Should try it with long and lat values?

Is there a basic tutorial for newbees like me?